# Germany my residency card has expired

Tags: germany, residency

My wife is German, and I'm American. We have been living in Germany for a few years now, and my residency card has expired. We have been afraid to try to renew it because we noticed it was expired after it happened. It is a little over a year overdue. What are our options? I am self employed and it doesn't matter where we live, we just want to live together in the EU. Is it still possible to renew my residency card, or will I get deported if I try?

Comment: As this is a question about long term residency, I move it to our sister site.

Comment: A deportation will be **extremely** unlikely unless they suspect your marriage of being a sham. I would be much more concerned about the tax status of your self-employed business. Did you file taxes? If so, your presence is on record anyway.

Comment: @John, You're more likely to get a stern talking to rather than anything even remotely leading to deportation. Just get it done and move on.